# How can change Textsize of activity_main_drawer in Navigation drawer activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity, layout

I want to change some feature of activity_main_drawer for example textsize and text color.
How can i do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Emergency"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="My way"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

I use this line in my item tag but do not work:

> android:textSize="@dimen/fontsizelayout"

Comment: use Custom Style for your navigation

Comment: @faiz mir i am a newbie can you tell me step by step?